# PHP login script - User profile loop

Tags: php, session, loops

The system I'm using doesn't have an option to view other users' profiles (Only your own) (By other users' profiles I mean something like `http://domain.com/profile.php?user=USERNAME`). However, the original one, has it.
I want to implant it in the new system so I created a new php file for the profile.

I downloaded this login system:
http://tympanus.net/codrops/2009/09/16/php-login-system-reloaded-v1-1/

It is a custom version of this system:
http://jpmaster77forum.conceptbb.com/t1-php-login-system-with-admin-features-download

Here is the original `userinfo.php` code:

```
<?
include("include/session.php");
?>

<html>
<title>Jpmaster77's Login Script</title>
<body>

<?
/* Requested Username error checking */
$req_user = trim($_GET['user']);
if(!$req_user || strlen($req_user) == 0 ||
   !eregi("^([0-9a-z])+$", $req_user) ||
   !$database->usernameTaken($req_user)){
   die("Username not registered");
}

/* Logged in user viewing own account */
if(strcmp($session->username,$req_user) == 0){
   echo "<h1>My Account</h1>";
}
/* Visitor not viewing own account */
else{
   echo "<h1>User Info</h1>";
}

/* Display requested user information */
$req_user_info = $database->getUserInfo($req_user);

/* Username */
echo "<b>Username: ".$req_user_info['username']."</b><br>";

/* Email */
echo "<b>Email:</b> ".$req_user_info['email']."<br>";

/**
 * Note: when you add your own fields to the users table
 * to hold more information, like homepage, location, etc.
 * they can be easily accessed by the user info array.
 *
 * $session->user_info['location']; (for logged in users)
 *
 * ..and for this page,
 *
 * $req_user_info['location']; (for any user)
 */

/* If logged in user viewing own account, give link to edit */
if(strcmp($session->username,$req_user) == 0){
   echo "<br><a href=\"useredit.php\">Edit Account Information</a><br>";
}

/* Link back to main */
echo "<br>Back To [<a href=\"main.php\">Main</a>]<br>";

?>

</body>
</html>
```

And this is my new `profile.php`:

```
<?php
include('config/db_con.php');
include('config/config.php');
$page = 'profile';
include('header.php');
require_once("php/core.php");

$objCore = new Core();

$objCore->initSessionInfo();
$objCore->initFormController();

    mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect");
    mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");
$get_email = $objCore->getSessionInfo()->getUserInfo('email');
$get_flname = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE email = '$get_email'";
$res = mysql_query($get_flname) or die(mysql_error());
$rows = mysql_fetch_array($res);
$gemail_hash = md5( strtolower( trim( "$get_email" ) ) );
$req_user = trim(strtolower(str_replace(" ", "", $rows['flname'])));
?> 
<div class="content">
    <div class="left">
        <div class="top_box" style="margin-top:0px;">
            <p><h90>Profile: <?php echo $rows['flname']; ?></h90><?php echo $req_user; ?></p>
        </div>
        <div class="box_pad">
            <div class="box" style="border-bottom:1px solid #dbdbdd;">  
                <?php if($objCore->getSessionInfo()->isLoggedIn()){ ?>
                        <img class="gravatar" src="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/<?php echo $gemail_hash; ?>?d=mm" />
                        <h1><?php echo $rows['flname']; ?></h1><br />
                        <a href="editaccount.php">[Edit Account]</a>
                        <? if($objCore->isAdmin()) ?>
                            <a href="admin.php">[admin]</a>
                        <a href="php/corecontroller.php?logoutaction=1">[Logout]</a>
                        <? }else{ ?> 
                        blabla test
                        <? } ?>

       <?php unset($objCore); ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
        <? include('ad.php'); ?> 
    </div> 
</div>
<?include('footer.php');?>
</body>
```

It doesn't work 'cause when trying to access other users' profiles, I see mine again.
How is the `file.php?user=USERNAME` url pattern is defined?

Thank you so much!
I really need this and I couldn't find anything on Google, since I didn't really know what to search for.
Sorry if there's information lacking, I tried to be as descriptive as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that is some bad programming in a long time.

1. Short tags are evil, and like all big communities advice DO NOT USE THEM. Using a script written by someone using shorttags is even worse.
2. **trim(strtolower(str_replace(**..... if the username is in the database with spaces/capital letters, why strip it here ?? and not before it gets INTO the datase.

I could go on but wouldn't solve your problem....

anyway :

```
$get_email = $objCore->getSessionInfo()->getUserInfo('email');
$get_flname = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE email = '$get_email'";
```

in your code, means that you are fetching the data based on the users session. thus not the one in the url part.

in the original :

```
$req_user = trim($_GET['user']);
if(!$req_user || strlen($req_user) == 0 ||
   !eregi("^([0-9a-z])+$", $req_user) ||
   !$database->usernameTaken($req_user)){
   die("Username not registered");
}
```

will get the user info from the URL.

Though, one question, why are you complicating life ?  why use profile.php for something it is not intended to ? if you are trying to do what i am thinking, you should rename 
**profile.php => myaccount.php**
AND 
**userinfo.php => profile.php**

would un-complicate your life for sure. also remember to rename the references.

Comment: 1. Thanks for the advice. I will replace them.
2. Because I also render the name in the user profile. so stripping the space before inserting to the database won't help.

Thanks for the answer. I will try it and comment here with the outcome.

Comment: "so stripping the space before inserting to the database won't help" that DOES help, stripping it for output us useless. If user is allowed to use spaces, capital letters it is only confusing if it cannot be seen in the output.